# Angular | Mocha Unit Testing

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocha.js

I have designed a login page using angularjs and now need to perform unit testing on it using Mocha.How to proceed ? I have no idea of Mocha ? Links to any good tutorials on mocha will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I entered 'Mocha testing' in google and got quite a few hits with sites that give both information and tutorials.

like [this](http://www.scotchmedia.com/tutorials/express/authentication/1/03) one, or the official [mocha](http://mochajs.org/) website, or [thisone](https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-node-js-and-mocha)...

The list goes on and on, google is your friend.